# Как получить путь до раздела через дескриптор HKEY

Tags: c++, c, winapi, реестр

Появилась необходимость получать путь до раздела, имея только Дескриптор`HKEY`.
Все перерыл, не нашел никакого рабочего метода. Много примеров с функцией экспортируемой ntdll `NtQueryKey`. Она рабочая, но она не работает с Дескрипторами, которыми работают стандартные winAPI функции из `winreg.h`. И я всегда получаю ошибку `Invalid Handle`, когда хочу передать какой-нибудь `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` или дескриптор, открытый с помощью `RegOpenKey`. На самом деле я не совсем понимаю, почему для `NtQueryKey` эти дескрипторы не являются действительными. Может быть эти дескрипторы разделены на User-Mode access и Kernel-Mode-access. Так же кто то писал сохранять информацию о дескрипторе с помощью `RegSaveKeyA` и потом читать из файла, но такой вариант не подходит.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-nt-and-zw-versions-of-the-native-system-services-routines

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` это predefined key, который константа, не настоящий хендл. Его даже нельзя дублировать через DuplicateHandle. Константы эти заменяются на настоящие дескрипторы при переходе от Win32 API к NT API. Если же передать такую константу в RegOpenKey, то она вернёт ту же константу.